# Snails on a sphere

Tags: geometry, curves

I am trying a variation of snails moving in an equilateral triangle.

Suppose that you have $6$ snails arranged on the the surface of a  sphere such that they are equidistant from each other. All the snails are numbered from $1$ to $6$. The snail numbered $1$ moves toward snail numbered $2$,  and $2$ moves towards $3$, $3$ moves towards $4$, $4$ moves towards $5$, $5$ moves towards $6$, $6$ moves towards $1$,

If they all move at a certain speed $v$ what kind of path will they take? will they all converge? when will they converge?

Comment: There is something wrong about the initial configuration. I cannot imagine how to place $6$ snails on the sphere so that all of them are equidistant from each other unless you place all of them at the same point...

Comment: There is precisely one way to place the $6$ snails on the sphere (up to rotations). They will be on the vertices of an inscribed octahedron.

Comment: Though it is not clear to me how snail $1$ will move toward snail $2$ if they are precisely across from eachother...

Comment: @Servaes achille hui is correct:  no such configuration of six snails on the surface of a sphere is possible.  Your proposed configuration does not work because any given snail is equidistant from four other snails, but the snail that is diametrically opposite is farther away.

Comment: I see now, it must have been late when I posted that (: Though the question is still worth asking for $4$ snails arranged equidistantly from eachother.

Comment: Here is what I find: For four snails arranged equidistantly, the won't converge. their trajectories will ultimately approach a great circle as a limit cycle. However, this limit cycle is only semistable. If you put 4 snails symmetrically on a great circle (say the one on $xy$-plane) and then move their initial positions a little bit for the same amount into upper hemisphere, the 4 snails will converge at the north pole in finite time.